# Construct a date using a column's value to compare against a range (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to query our employee table to return all the employees who are celebrating a hiring-date anniversary within the next week. Here's the query:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, hiredate
FROM   employees
WHERE  hiredate IS NOT NULL
AND    DateFromParts(Year(getdate()),Month(hiredate),Day(hiredate)) BETWEEN getDate() AND DateAdd(day,7,getDate())
```

The `hiredate` column is a datetime column with the month, day, and year they were hired.  I thought using `DateFromParts` would let me construct their anniversary date for this year so I could compare that to the date range.  But it's throwing the error:

> Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values
>   which are not valid.

Am I on the right track and just missed something, or is there a better way?

Comment: It sounds like you have someone that has a HireDate on Feb 29 of a leap year, and it cannot create the same date for this year.

Comment: You're absolutely right!  I added `AND NOT (Month(hiredate) = 2 AND Day(hiredate) = 29)` and it worked. So, obviously I don't want to skip those people.  What's a good alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by someone having a HireDate of Feb 29 during a Leap Year, and since this year is not a Leap Year, it is failing to construct the valid date.

Try using the following to construct the date based on the number of days since the beginning of the year:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, hiredate
FROM   employees
WHERE  hiredate IS NOT NULL
AND    Case When Month(hiredate) = 2 And Day(hiredate) = 29 Then
           DateAdd(Day, DatePart(DayOfYear, hiredate) - 1, DateFromParts(Year(getdate()), 1, 1))
   Else    DateFromParts(Year(getdate()), Month(hiredate), Day(hiredate))
End BETWEEN getDate() AND DateAdd(day,7,getDate())
```

Comment: I added a `CASE` statement in the edit to account for dates after the Leap Day in a year being shifted incorrectly.

Comment: Caution: This query will not return the correct result near the end of the year.

Comment: @dnoeth Thank you for that.  How would you correct it?

Comment: See my post :-)  I used to do this kind of question in my trainings, after the first students finished their queries I added a `feb-29` birthday and let them run it at `dec-30` :-)))

Comment: I see it too... If the `hiredate` is 1/1/2010 and today is 12/31/2015, the `DateFromParts` will create 1/1/2015 and check if it's between 12/31/2015 and 1/6/2016.  This will say the hiredate is not in the range, while the desired result is that it IS within the range.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to find if someone had his birthday within a given period uses following approach:

- calculate the age the day before the start of the period: `age1`
- calculate the age at the end of the period (you will need that anyway to know the exact age): `age2`
- now check if the age changed; `WHERE age1 <> age2`

Calculating an age in SQL Server is horrible, but as this is a common task you might have a UDF already, otherwise:

```
DATEDIFF (YEAR, birthdate, 
          GETDATE()) 
- CASE WHEN 100 * MONTH(GETDATE()) + DAY(GETDATE())
          < 100 * MONTH(birthdate) + DAY(birthdate) 
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
  END AS age
```

Now adjust it using `DateAdd(day,-1,getDate())` and `DateAdd(day,7,getDate())`